# Crossing power (ground) domains on a PCB with a digital signal

Tags: power, pcb, ground, ground-loop, io

I have a circuit with a common battery "ground" and a few non-isolated voltage regulators. In order to minimize electrical noise on the printed circuit board I've taken care to maintain a clear return path of each circuit back to its voltage source. In the image below I'm showing this is as the current loops in pink (1) and (2). I do this although `GND_A` and `GND_B` are the same electrical node.

I also have a signal that is generated from a circuit powered by `U1`. For simplicity, this is shown as the output of a voltage divider below. In the real application this is a digital signal which is driven by a buffer and toggles high/low at some undetermined rate and depending on other inputs. This signal is then fed as a digital input to `U4` (3).

The question is regarding signal (3), which crosses power "*domains*". Specifically, I'm interested in controlling how current flows back to its source in the physical layout and if there are best practices for minimizing noise in a circuit such as this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current 3 is a loop, too, as are all currents!

Depending on if it is positive or negative, it will take different return paths:

- Positive: through U4, the common ground, battery, U1 and R1.
- Negative: through R2, the battery, the common power rail, U3 and U4

So your suspicion is well warranted. When you cross power domains like this, the return currents can be quite large and typically involve at least the nearest common node. So make sure that Current 3 only contains low frequency signals (edge rate control for digital signals) and that the layout between these domains is also tidy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the positive/negative current paths. Would it help if `GND_A` and `GND_B` were tied together near physical crossing point of the power domains? In the past I've also seen ferrites/inductors used for connecting 2 grounds, such as these, together.

Comment: @jairo It's almost always bad to split the ground at all, unless you require isolation. So best make a good continous, low impedance solid common ground. If you lay out the common power and common ground tightly on the whole board (e.g. route the 9V directly over a solid ground plane in layer2), then the loop area won't be so terrible even though it will involve many components. That is the strategy I would pursue. And absolutely limit the bandwidth of this current 3 to the lowest you need for function.

Comment: @jairo Oh and of course, place decoupling capacitors between 9V and GND close to U1 and U3.. That way, the higher frequency content of Current 3 won't have to travel all the way to the battery.